# for loop with 2 vectors to calculate power in R fails

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, vector

I have 2 vectors containing numbers, I'm using to simulate power of my study but keeps getting this error at the `for loop` section

```
Error in pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1 = i, n2 = j, sig.level = 0.05) : 
  number of observations in the first group must be at least 2
```

would be grateful for your suggestions to get it working

##sample code

```
grp1.n <- seq(30,150,5)  ##group 1, N
grp2.n <- seq(30,150,5)-15  ## group 2, N - 15

h=0.85 #specify large effect size

grp1.length <- length(grp1.n)
grp2.length <- length(grp2.n)

power.holder <- array(numeric(grp1.length*grp2.length), dim=c(grp1.length,grp2.length),dimnames=list(grp1.n,grp2.n))

for (i in 1:grp1.length){
  for (j in 1:grp2.length){
    result.pwr.2p2n.test <- pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1=i, n2=j, sig.level=0.05)
    power.holder[i,j] <- ceiling(result.pwr.2p2n.test$power)
    return(result.pwr.2p2n.test)
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. In your inner loop you pass i and j to the pwoer calc function. But n1 and n2 have to be at least 2. but since your i and j loop start at 1 this will fail.

Comment: pls how can i make the `power calc function` take the actual numbers in the vectors? I tried this but still fails. thanks for your help. `for (i in 1:length(grp1.n)){
  for (j in 1:length(grp2.n)){
    result.pwr.2p2n.test <- pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1=i, n2=j, sig.level=0.05)
    power.holder[j,i] <- ceiling(result.pwr.2p2n.test$power)
    return(result.pwr.2p2n.test)
  }
}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but I think it is:

```
grp1.n <- seq(30,150,5)  ##group 1, N
grp2.n <- seq(30,150,5)-15  ## group 2, N - 15

h=0.85 #specify large effect size

grp1.length <- length(grp1.n)
grp2.length <- length(grp2.n)

power.holder <- array(numeric(grp1.length*grp2.length), dim=c(grp1.length,grp2.length),dimnames=list(grp1.n,grp2.n))

for (i in 1:grp1.length){
  for (j in 1:grp2.length){
    result.pwr.2p2n.test <- pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1=grp1.n[i], n2=grp2.n[j], sig.level=0.05)
    power.holder[i,j] <- ceiling(result.pwr.2p2n.test$power)
    return(power.holder)
  }
}
```

The changes are in the pwr.2p2n.test function as well as the object you want to return.

Old: `pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1=i, n2=j, sig.level=0.05)`
New: `pwr.2p2n.test(h, n1=grp1.n[i], n2=grp2.n[j], sig.level=0.05)`

Note there was also a missing } bracket in your code.